# Passing object as props to jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

I have an object contains multiple common key-value props, that I want to pass on to some jsx. Something like this:

```
const commonProps = {myProp1: 'prop1',myProp2: 'prop2'};
<MyJsx commonProps />
```

I want this to function as passing individual props:

```
<MyJsx myProp1={commonProps.myProp1} myProp2={commonProps.myProp2}/>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. `<MyJsx myObjProps={commonProps} />`

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jwxzth

Answer (score 256, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes its possible, but the way you are sending it is not correct.

The meaning of `<MyJsx commonProps />` is:

```
<MyJsx commonProps={true} />
```

So if you don't specify any value, by default it will take `true`. To pass the object, you need to write it like this:

```
const commonProps = {myProp1: 'prop1',myProp2: 'prop2'};
<MyJsx commonProps={commonProps} />
```

**Update:**

If you have an object and want to pass all the properties as separate prop, write it like this:

```
<MyJsx {...commonProps} />
```

Comment: This is not what I need. I edited my question so it will be more clear. I need the props to be sent as individual props

Comment: updated the answer, please check. Write it like this: `<MyJsx {...commonProps} />`

Comment: just what I needed

Comment: Yes! Else I ended up doing things like `<p>{props.props.hello}</p>`

Comment: What about a single value?
Instead of <Component prop1={prop1} />, something like <Component {...prop1} />
Can't get it working.

Comment: it's destructuring it, which if it's a string would be the same as saying 

    const prop1 = 'string' 
      <Component {...prop1} />
      // is the same as
     <Component s='s' t='t' r='r' i='i' n='n' g='g' />
Or
    const prop1= {name:'dave', id:'123abc'}
     <Component {..prop1} />
     // is the same as
    <Component name={prop1.name} id={prop1.id}/>

Answer (score 80):

You can use the [spread operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) to do this.

You can simply do `<MyJsx {...commonProps} />`

Now what all individual properties you have in commonProps will be sent as individual props to MyJsx.

Comment: This trick allowed me to switch 10 lines of code for 1. Much appreciated!

Comment: +1. Very cool. Just beware: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md

Answer (score 19):

You need to use double braces, like this:

```
messages={{tile:'Message 1'}}
```

Or to pass many objects:

```
messages={[{title:'Message 1', name: 'Andrew'}, {title:'Message 2', name: 'Greg'}]}
```

It's simply JS syntax inside braces.

A final component might look like this

```
<Chat title="Some str" messages={[{title:'Message 1', name: 'Andrew'}, {title:'Message 2', name: 'Greg'}]} />
```

Answer (score 10):

You can pass props as object in two ways:-

const commonProps = {myProp1: 'prop1',myProp2: 'prop2'};

1.Using spread Operator:-

```
<MyJsx {...commonProps} />
```

2.Simply pass that props:-

```
<MyJsx commonProps = {commonProps ? commonProps : true} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also do something like this:

```
<MyJsx objectProps={{
    prop1,
    prop2
}}/>
```

This way you don't have to write `prop1: prop1` (if it is a variable or function such as `state` `setState`).

It can then be accessed in the component using destructuring: `let { prop1, prop2 } = props.objectProps`

Answer (score 1):

```
const object={name:'xyz',age:50}
```

use double braces as follows

```
<Message  {{object}}/>
```

*Child*

```
function Message({object}){  
    //You can get object here.//
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had for some object types errors in typescript. as const helped here.

```
const myprops = { YOUR OBJECT } as const
```