# Ways to avoid the Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a component that dispatches some actions when a state somewhere else in the app changes.
But this is somehow giving me the dreaded `change in the order of Hooks` error.

In reading the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) it says basically wrapping hooks in conditionals is verboten... Which I am not currently doing.

However I am rendering lists of items and the values of those lists changes, as the server loads data. Using selectors and redux-sagas makes all of this pretty impossible to actually debug, so how else might I track down the root of the problem?

I have one component:

```js
const PhraseList = props => {
    const trainingPhrases = useSelector(selectFilteredPhrases());

    return (
        <div className={styles.Wrapper}>
            <ul className={opStyles.listReset}>
                {  
                    trainingPhrases.map((phrase, idx) => {
                        return PhraseItem({ phrase, idx });
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
```

which calls the `PhraseItem` component, which throws an Error.

```js
const PhraseItem = ({ phrase, idx }) => {
    // this line chokes
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    return (
        <li key={"tr-" + idx}>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <div className={styles.phraseText}>{phrase.text}</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
};
```

I'm debugging changes in the selector (selector factory) and that is what seems to trigger the app to crash.

```
export const selectFilteredPhrases = () =>
    createSelector(trainingPhrases, phraseFilter, (trainingPhrases, phraseFilter) => {
        console.log('trainingPhrases', trainingPhrases)
        return trainingPhrases
    });
```

but if data didn't change ever, it's hard to buidl an app :O

I saw [an answer about using JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397395/react-has-detected-a-change-in-the-order-of-hooks-but-hooks-seem-to-be-invoked) which I don't think is relevant. And not much else on this issue.

redux, sagas, hooks, selectors... the react DSL is more and more layers and it's hard to debug deep in the framework.

UPDATE. I think this *might* be because I'm calling two sagas one after the other and this causes some kind of race condition in the UI?

```
    const pickIntent = () => {
        dispatch(pickIntentAction(intentId));
        dispatch(getIntentPhrasesAction(intentId));
```

[image: debuglog]

Comment: Can you test something for me: replace `return PhraseItem({ phrase, idx });` with `return <PhraseItem phrase={phrase} idx={idx} />;`

Comment: @david I owe you a beer! The answer was staring me in the face. Thanks so much! The difference between JSX and JS is sometimes not noticeable...

Answer (score 0):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397395/react-has-detected-a-change-in-the-order-of-hooks-but-hooks-seem-to-be-invoked) is related, as it is already mentioned in this link, if you call the jsx component as a function react thinks that, hooks which are declared in this jsx function is part of the app component, so if your array `trainingPhrases` has fewer element on the first render than on the second one it will cause this warning (there will be less rendered jsx components, which means there will be less hooks). solution is simple call jsx component like this `<PhraseItem phrase={phrase} idx={idx} />`

Comment: Guess this should be a community wiki since the solution has been comment above.

Comment: Yes I actually found that answer and read it but skimmed over my code and missed it.