# Conditional Rendering in React won't work, state not working properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

i'm trying to have a component only render when I have used a search button.

The code below is my current code

### Update

Made the changes,
Now receiving this error.

error ] ERROR in /home/holborn/Documents/Work/Portfolio/Data_Scraping/Eldritch/client/pages/index.tsx(21,19):
21:19 Cannot find name 'Product'.
    19 |   interface OutputProps {
    20 |     searched?: string

> 21 |     productList?: Product[]
>          |                   ^
>       22 | }
>       23 | 
>       24 | const Output: React.FC = ({ searched, productList }) => {

This is the array for product list when the search is made

### after following other question i get this error.

```
JSX element type 'void' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
    262 | 
    263 |   return (
  > 264 |     <Output columns={columns} message={message} handleSearch={handleSearch} searchRef={searchRef} productList={productList}/>
        |     ^
    265 | 
    266 |   );
    267 | }
```

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Comment: Tried to cut it down, thanks for the advice!

Comment: The syntax `<Output data = {searched,productList}/>` does not match the type signature of `Output({ searched, productList })`. It looks like you want to pass in two props instead, which can be done in one of two ways: `<Output {{ searched, productList }} />` or `<Output searched={searched} productList={productList} />` should compile

Comment: @MichaelHolborn, Could you please fork this https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-typescript-template-3re10 next js typescript codesandbox  and input your code, which would be much better to understand your problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expect the output component to have `productList` and `searched` as props however you pass it `data` as a prop

Secondly you must define the interface directly and not as a function

```
 interface OutputProps {
    searched?: string
    productList?: Product[]
}

...


<Output searched={searched} productList={productList}/>
```

Comment: Still have the same issue using this. My updated code includes this, but still breaks.

Comment: Did you change the interface, since it could be the reason you see this error

Comment: Does it still not work? have you ensured that you have defined the interface correctly and not as a function

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down your code:

```js
function Output(searched,productList) {
  if (!searched && !productList) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <div>
            <p></p>

            {/* <Chart data={productList} /> */}
          </div>
          <table className="table-auto">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th className="px-4 py-2">Name</th>
                <th className="px-4 py-2">Price</th>
                <th className="px-4 py-2">Brand</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {productList.map((e, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td className="border px-4 py-2">{e.Product}</td>
                  <td className="border px-4 py-2">{e.Price}</td>
                  <td className="border px-4 py-2">{e.Brand}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
  );
}
```

```
            <Output data = {etc}/>
```

However, this is invalid. when you call a component through JSX(ie. `<Output/>`), React will excpect that `Output` is called with a single `props` argument, not multiple arguments. (besides, your `etc` is undefined here)

so you might have meant to do this:

```
// place your parameters inside an object, commonly referred to as "props"
function Output({ searched, productList }) {
```

And, since you're using Typescript, you can leverage the type system to work for you:

```js
interface OutputProps {
    searched?: string
    productList?: Product[]
}

const Output: React.FC<OutputProps> = ({ searched, productList }) => {
  // Typescript infers searched and productList typing here
  if(!searched && !productList) {
    return null;
  }
  ...
}
```

and while we're at it, **please** format your code. Look into [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) to make sure your code stays consistent and easy to read.

Comment: Got an error just then, typescript is a little confusing for me, any idea on what i've done wrong?

Comment: assume something to do with Type's!

Comment: You're passing your data incorrectly. This isn't even a typescript problem, I recommend you study a bit more about JavaScript objects and how they are passed to react components

Comment: No problem. I have tried using this as an example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081549/passing-object-as-props-to-jsx ,
yet come up against the same error.